# get array values based on checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a situation where there are 3 check box ("initially checked"). Since it as 3 check box it will use ng-repeat for 3 time and loops the division for there time. Now once i uncheck any of the check box it should display div for 2 time. So far ,

```
$scope.items = [
    {id: 0, title: "apple",selected:true},
    {id: 1, title: "orange",selected:true},
    {id: 2, title: "grapes",selected:true},     
];
```

On ng-click in each check box i have called a function test("apple").

```
$scope.test = function(vals) {
    $scope.vl=[];
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.items.length;i++) {
        if($scope.items[i].title == vals) {
            console.log("dnt push");
        }
        else {
            $scope.vl.push({
                id: $scope.items[i].id,
                title: $scope.items[i].title,
                selected:true                      
            });
        }
    } 
    console.log("vl array");
    console.log($scope.vl);
}
```

Problem I am facing is it works fine for 1st uncheck but not when i do for multiple uncheck. When i check unchecked its not loading div.

In HTML I am using like,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vl"> some tags </div>
```

Comment: what did you want to do precisly ?

Answer (score 2):

not quite sure about your question, but hope my answer can give you some hints.

[plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dR62a1eHTd8xuCAbnOPL?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.items = [{
    id: 0,
    title: "apple",
    selected: true
  }, {
    id: 1,
    title: "orange",
    selected: true
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: "grapes",
    selected: true
  }];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.8"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected">{{item.title}}
  </div>
  {{items | json}}
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If and only if you want to put in an array the item who are checked :

http://plnkr.co/edit/DvoPBBvKf3AhYM4qcBhx?p=preview

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <input type="checkbox" 
        ng-model="item.selected" ng-click="test(item.title)"> {{item.title}}
</div>
```

**controller**

```
$scope.test = function(vals) {
  $scope.vl=[];
  $scope.vlChecked=[];
  for(var i=0;i<$scope.items.length;i++) {
    if($scope.items[i].selected) {
      $scope.vlChecked.push({
        id: $scope.items[i].id,
        title: $scope.items[i].title,
        selected:true                    
      });
    }
  } 

  console.log("vlChecked array");
  console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.vlChecked));

}
```